# Does JRE Installation automatically defines PATH and JAVA_HOME on Windows?

Tags: java

I am installing JRE on windows server 2012 (which is a production server). I want to know if the installation will automatically update/create PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variable. I have no place to test it and hence asking this question.

Also want to know, does Java update automatically updates JAVA_HOME as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Non you have to add that variable manually through windows properties, and also you have to add the path to bin directory to the path variable

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I guess you have to check, because it might be some changes in the path with the changes of the versions